# Let P and Q represent formulas. Would stuff like $(P \wedge \neg P) \models Q$ make sense?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, model-theory

I confess, I am in a state of total confusion right now. And I am still struggling to grasp the underlying distinction between the normal material implication, $\Rightarrow$, and the notion of semantic consequence, $\models$.

I've seen stuff like $(P \wedge \neg P) \models Q$ appear in a book I'm currently reading (*A First Course in Logic*, by Shawn Hedman), but at the end of the day, it had me wondering what the difference is between material implication and semantic consequence. I mean, ***really***.

We all know that the sentence $(P \wedge \neg P) \Rightarrow Q$ is a tautology. And in a *material* sense (only thinking in terms of truth values and not in terms of how the two formulas P and Q are connected semantically), this is totally acceptable to me. But to write stuff like $(P \wedge \neg P) \models Q$  blows my entire understanding of the difference between $\Rightarrow$ and $\models$ right out the window. I thought the double turnstile symbol is only to be used in a sense that has more to do with the underlying meaning/interpretation behind the sentences? Like, if we say $P \models Q$ (where P and Q are sentences), then wouldn't it mean that we can see a clear logical connection which allows us to accept that Q follows from P?

If translated into words, the sentence "formula Q is a semantic consequence of $P \wedge \neg P$" is incomprehensible to me. It doesn't have that logical connection that I thought must accompany every use of the double turnstile symbol (for instance, I can easily accept $(P \wedge Q) \models P$, because the logical connection is there, after all if its stated that P and Q are both true, then *logically*, P must be true). If no logical connection is required for the use of $\models$, then how is it different from the normal material implication?

It feels like I'm missing something crucial, like a bigger picture, or a wider generalization of what the double turnstile symbol represents.

Comment: $P\models Q$ means that any model satisfying $P$ also satisfies $Q$. With a completeness/soundness theorem, and a deduction theorem, this is the same as $\vdash P\implies Q$. One of the points of $P\land \neg P\models Q$ (which also holds intuitionistically, where $\implies$ is not material) is that a contradiction should be read as "everything", rather than as "false".

Comment: @Max Hi. I appreciate the response. But i'm still confused, to be honest. Is it possible to explain it in more layman terms? How does one interpret $(P \wedge \neg P) \models Q$ in a way that jibes with the concept of "semantic consequence"?

Comment: Well $Q$ is a semantic consequence of $P\land \neg P$ because in every possibility in which $P\land \neg P$ holds (there is no such possibility !) , $Q$ holds as well. Semantics is about possible worlds, so this is why that's called semantic implication

Comment: As far as I can tell, your difficulty comes from the part of your question that says "we can see a clear logical connection". That's far too vague to be mathematics. If, by "clear logical connection", you mean something that includes truth tables, then you're probably OK, because truth tables do allow you to infer $Q$ from $P\land\neg P$. But if you mean something more vague than truth tables, then you need to revise your understanding of $\models$.

Comment: @Max "With a completeness/soundness theorem, and a deduction theorem, this is the same as ⊢P⟹Q."  No, inter-derivability does not mean sameness.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood it should be clear to anyone reading my comment that "same as" here is an abuse of language meaning "equivalent to", please don't bicker about details like that.

Comment: @Max No, your statements are not logically equivalent.  $\vdash$ refers to syntactic provability which means one can *literally* produce whatever is on the right side of the $\vdash$.  One cannot literally produce any formula of the form P⟹Q since no well-formed formula has that form.  Also, P|=Q is meta-linguistic, and abbreviates {P}|=Q, while (P⟹Q) is object-linguistic.  Object language and meta language statements are not equivalent in general.  Usually, meta-language statements has more expressive power, while object language statements are clearer in terms of their validity.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood so you're telling me that $P\models Q$ and $\vdash (P\implies Q)$ are not logically equivalent with a completeness/soundess theorem and a deduction theorem ? (again, the parentheses issue being unnecessary bickering about a technical uninteresting issue here)

Comment: @Max Yes, they are not logically equivalent solely under the conditions you've put forth.  You would need modus ponens as a rule of inference.  And systems of propositional logic exist without such a rule of inference.  Also, logical equivalence is an object-linguistic concept in terms of computable truth values.  I have no reason to suppose it as a meta-linguistic concept.

Comment: @Max That's exactly the difficulty that I'm facing right now. If we were to accept what you said in your second comment, then what difference is there really between $\models$ and $\Rightarrow$? That's just saying that $P \wedge \neg P$ materially implies $Q$, isn't it?

Comment: @Max The ONLY way my befuddled mind can come into terms with everything at this point is that the usage of $\models$ (e.g, $P \models Q$) is to EXPLICITLY state that $P \Rightarrow Q$ is a tautology. Like, we can make compound statements like $P \Rightarrow Q$ everywhere, but the material implication can still be false. And the $\models$ is just a way of saying that the material implication is a tautology? Is that the right way to understand all of this?

Comment: @AndreasBlass 

Yes. I definitely need to revise my understanding of $\models$'s usage. In fact, right now I don't even know what I know anymore. 

I agree with you that 'clear logical connection' is far too vague and imprecise for mathematics. But sadly that's the only way I can express it. Maybe I should clarify what I meant by that. 

Thing is, statements like $(P \wedge Q) \models P$ is comprehensible to me in terms of semantic implication, because we can reason out the truth of $P$ logically. We can infer the truth of P using the truth of $(P \wedge Q)$... (to be continued)

Comment: continued from above...

@AndreasBlass
But how do we do that for $(P \wedge \neg P) \models Q$? We can't reason (or infer) the truth of Q based on $P \wedge \neg P$ (or can we??). I mean, there's just no connection there. All we know from $(P \wedge \neg P)$ is that it is an absurdity, and that's it? There's nothing at all about $Q$.That's what I mean by 'clear logical connection'. I must apologize for the imprecise use of terms here, I have very little background in logic. In fact, this is my first attempt.

Comment: @AndreasBlass

After reading all your constructive comments, I have come to the conclusion that $P \models Q$ is a way to explicitly state that $P \Rightarrow Q$ is a tautological statement. What I mean by this is, that we can have sentences like $P \Rightarrow Q$, but that sentence can still be a falsehood. But if we say $P \models Q$, then there is no chance at all that $P \Rightarrow Q$ can be false? (that it is a tautology) Am I on the right track here? Or is this just another fantasy that my confused mind had conjured upon?

Comment: @DougSpoonwood : mhm no here there's no need for modus ponens here. But nevermind it's clear that you don't understand what all this is about and to not pollute these comments I'll stop answering to you.

Comment: Anthony : the point is that stating "$P\implies Q$" makes no sense because there is no interpretation for $P$, nor for $Q$. So you say $P\models Q$ to say that this doesn't depend on the interpretation. And indeed, with all the theorems that I mentioned, this is equivalent to $\models P\implies Q$ which means exactly that $P\implies Q$ is a tautology. But what else would you want it to mean ? As Andres Blass mentioned, the notion of "logical connection" is not mathematical"

Comment: @Max Modus ponens is usually needed to prove that "If |-(P⟹Q), then P|-Q."

Comment: @Anthony "But how do we do that for (P∧¬P)⊨Q? We can't reason (or infer) the truth of Q based on P∧¬P (or can we??)."  In sound systems, it's possible to reason out (P∧¬P)|=Q.  Something like the following usually works.  We assume (P∧¬P).  Then we assume $\lnot$Q.  Then we get a contradiction from the first assumption.  So, we have ($\lnot$Q$\rightarrow$(P∧¬P)) or ($\lnot$Q$\vdash$(P∧¬P)).  Thus, we discharge $\lnot$Q and have Q under the assumption of (P∧¬P).  So, (P∧¬P)$\vdash$Q.  By soundness, (P∧¬P)|=Q.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood i appreciate the response. But i am new to this topic, and have insufficient background in formal mathematics to know the full implications of concepts such as soundness and completeness. But i will read them up first before coming back and reread your comment. But meanwhile, it will be immensely helpful if you could express your answer in complete layman terms.

Comment: The basic issue is that we may have logical languages **without** the conditional *connective* ($\to, \Rightarrow$): we may use $\land, \lnot$ or $\lor, \lnot$ and they are enough to formalize arguments as well as the concept of *tautology*. But the concept of *logical consequence*: $\vDash$ does **not** change.

Comment: "the double turnstile symbol is only to be used in a sense that has more to do with the underlying meaning/interpretation behind the sentences?" YES... but in propositional logic the only "meaning" of a sentence is its TRUTH-VALUE.

Answer (score -5):

"We all know that the sentence (P∧¬P)⇒Q is a tautology."

I certainly don't know this and gasp when I see statements like this made.  Anyone who claims to is also, simply put, wrong.  Why things work that way helps to illuminate things.

To say that something is a tautology is to imply that something is an object-level sequence of symbols.  If you check your definition of a well-formed formula, or whatever equivalent term gets used, (P∧¬P)⇒Q is not well-formed.  Thus, (P∧¬P)⇒Q is not a tautology, because a tautology is by definition a well-formed formula.  ((P∧¬P)⇒Q) is a tautology.

On the other hand, (P∧¬P)⊨Q is a meta-language construct.  It is not well-formed in the object-language, and since the arity of the predicate |= seems to vary, there might not exist a corresponding well-formed formula (though maybe not also).  Also, |= is a predicate, while ((P∧¬P)⇒Q) doesn't have any predicates.

The difference might also get illuminated by looking at other uses of |=.  For instance, I think you agree that, "{p, (p⇒q)} |= q" makes sense.  Let's suppose that |= is no different from ⇒.  Then, "{p, (p⇒q)} |= q" is no different from "{p, (p⇒q)} ⇒ q".  There's at least three problems,

1. "{p, (p⇒q)} ⇒ q" is not well-formed, since all well-formed formal implications begin with a '(' and end with a ')'.
2. q is a proposition, but what we have on the left side of the arrow is a set.  But, sets of propositions are not propositions.  Nor are propositions sets of propositions.  So, again, "{p, (p⇒q)} ⇒ q" is not well-formed, and it's not even apparent how to make into a well-formed formula, or even necessarily the case that it can get made into a well-formed formula, since it would even two different types of entities needing to fall under the same roof... so to speak.  That sounds like a possible category error.

Pece has also commented that:

"... ⊨ is a relation between finite sequences of wffs on the left and wff on the right, while ⟹ is a binary connective in the language that is used to construct formulas."

Comment: Bickering about parentheses really isn't relevant here. Moreover, no one is claiming that $\models$ is the same as $\implies$ here. The OP asks what $\models$ is, why it's called semantic consequence, how it differs from material implication, how a sense of "logical connection" is attained: this has nothing to do with your answer

Comment: @Max It's not a bicker.  You can't have a valid rule of uniform substitution without parentheses.  That rule works out as essential for axiomatic systems which only have axioms and rules of inference.  |= is certainly a meta-language symbol, while ⟹ an object language symbol.

Comment: $(p \land \neg p) \implies q$  is a tautology. See the truth table at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth+table+(p+and+~p)+%3D%3E+q

Comment: @DanChristensen No, (p∧¬p)⟹q is not a tautology.  Every tautology is a well-formed formula, and (p∧¬p)⟹q is not a well-formed formula.

Comment: Then you had better write to Wolfram to, ummm... set them straight. Likewise Stanford whose online truth table generator agrees http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs103/tools/truth-table-tool/ Good luck with that. (Hee, hee!)

Comment: @DanChristensen If (p∧¬p)⟹q is a tautology, then by the rule of uniform substitution and substituting  (p∧¬p)⟹q for q, since tautologies can always get substituted for variables, then (p∧¬p)⟹ (p∧¬p)⟹q is a tautology.  But, (p∧¬p)⟹ (p∧¬p)⟹q is not a tautology.  (p∧¬p)⟹ (p∧¬p)⟹q is ambiguous.  The text of wolframalpha is also not consistent.  (p and ~p) => q is not the same as p$\land$$\lnot$p⟹q.  A CS class?  Why aren't you consulting mathematical logic texts by logicians?  Here's sections of Elliot Mendelsohn's text:

Comment: @DanChristensen "A statement form that is always true, no matter what the  truth values of its statement letters may be, is called a tautology."  For the definition of a 'statement form' see p. 13 here: https://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~krajicek/mendelson.pdf  "Statement form" is a synonym for "well-formed formula".  A basic requirement for well-formed formulas lies that they enable us to compute truth values of expressions uniquely.

Comment: In classical logic, $(p \land \neg p) \implies q$ is a wff and a tautology.

Comment: @DanChristensen No, (p∧¬p)⟹q is not a wff.  At least not from any workable definition.  Every wff can get demonstrated as a wff from the formation rules for a wff.  So, since you claim that (p∧¬p)⟹q is a wff, go ahead and *demonstrate* it as one by only using the formation rules.  You've made the claim, and thus the burden of proof lies with you.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula#Propositional_calculus Is this not a "workable definition?"

Comment: @DanChristensen That's workable.  From that definition, it's clear that every string where the primary connective (the primary connective would be the first symbol were the string to get translated to a prefix notation without parentheses) is binary, starts with a '(' and ends with a ')'.  Thus, if a string S does not start with a '(' and end with a ')', and the primary connective is binary, then S is not a wff.  So, (p∧¬p)⟹q  is not a wff ('⟹' is binary and the primary connective).  So again, where is your demonstration?  I'm not seeing it.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood Actually most mathematical textbook about model theory or proof theory establishes at some point $P \mathbin{\mathcal B} Q$ as syntactic sugar for $(P \mathbin{\mathcal B} Q)$ when it is not harmful (with $\mathcal B$ a binary connective). Moreover, replace everywhere in OP's question the "wrong" statement by your well-formed variation and still your answer does not address the question. At best, you could have just made it a comment.

Comment: @Pece I hope you agree that the OP did not understand the concept of a well-formed formula when he wrote it.  The OP writes: "But to write stuff like (P∧¬P)⊨Q blows my entire understanding of the difference between ⇒ and ⊨ right out the window."  But, this would not have happened had the distinction between well-formed formulas and other strings been clearer to the OP.  A difference between  ⇒  and |= lies in that  ⇒ can and does appear in well-formed formulas in propositional logic, while |= cannot and does not.  So-called "syntactic sugar" makes things like that LESS clear.  Also...

Comment: The OP writes: "I've seen stuff like (P∧¬P)⊨Q appear in a book I'm currently reading (A First Course in Logic, by Shawn Hedman), but at the end of the day, it had me wondering what the difference is between material implication and semantic consequence. I mean, really."  Well, in reality, material implication gets represented by symbols which can and do appear in well-formed formulas in propositional logic, while semantic consequence cannot and does not.  Thus, in reality, material implication is object linguistic and semantic consequence is meta-linguistic.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I think I understand what you were trying to say in you answer, namely that $\models$ is a relation between finite sequences of wffs on the left and wff on the right, while $\implies$ is a binary connective in the language that is used to construct formulas. If so, first I will remove my -1 because your answer is not about nitpicking,  but this is not at all clear that this is the message you want to convey, but secondly and more importantly I'm not even sure this is the problem OP is struggling on...

Comment: @DanChristensen You wrote that "((p∧¬q)⟹q) " is a tautology.  It's not.  Suppose q is false, and p is true.  I suppose that's a typo, but one little symbol can make a difference like that.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood So $((p \land \neg p) \implies q)$ with outer brackets is a wff and a tautology. That's what this is all about -- the outer brackets??? OMG

Comment: @DanChristensen OMG you believe that the outer brackets don't matter and you write theorem proving software???!!  Look, consider a simple system with just -> as a connective.  Suppose x->y is a wff.  Suppose the only axiom is (x->(y->x)).  Suppose the only rule of inference is uniform substitution.  And nothing more.  Let's substitute a->b for x in the axiom.  Then we have (a->b->(y->a->b)).  But, let's say we didn't know the substitution history.  We'd have no idea how to compute a->b->(y->a->b).  Oops!  What went wrong?  We didn't have two little parentheses in our definition of a wff!